# How to sort array contain double value in Kotlin?

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I have below kind of array,

```
val mArrayList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
mArrayList.add("10-12 YRS")
mArrayList.add("2-3 YRS")
mArrayList.add("4-5 YRS")
mArrayList.add("7-10 YRS")
mArrayList.add("5-7 YRS")
```

I have the above kind of ArrayList and I want to sort this ArrayList.
How to sort this kind of array?
Can anyone please help?

Comment: android tag + having it in the question is irrelevant, your question has nothing to do with android, it is a pure kotlin question. Now regarding the question itself, what is your expected output?

Comment: How do you want it sorted? First age? Second age? Difference in ages? Length of the string?

Comment: Voted to close because question is unanswerable until Alex and Todd's questions are answered.

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you have the `sortedBy`/`sortBy` methods to sort such a list. The first one returns a new list that is sorted, the second sorts the receiver list in-place.

The lambda you pass it allows you to extract the value you want to use for comparison.

For instance, you can use this to sort by the first integer in your elements:

```kotlin
val sorted = mArrayList.sortedBy { it.split("-").first().toInt() }
```

Or if you want to sort your list in place:

```kotlin
mArrayList.sortBy { it.split("-").first().toInt() }
```

In both cases, `it.split("-").first().toInt()` splits the string into 2 parts (before and after the dash), and converts the first part into an integer (which is comparable).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is the sort you are looking for:

```kotlin
mArrayList.sortBy { it.split("-", limit = 2)[0].toInt() }
println(mArrayList) //[2-3 YRS, 4-5 YRS, 5-7 YRS, 7-10 YRS, 10-12 YRS]
```